# Pairwise check of two columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which consists of three columns. The first column contains a number of id1's to be replaced by id2's from the second column. From the coloured cells you can see that id2's can also be found in the first column, which means that they are also replaced by other id'. My output should be for example, for the first id1 which is the yellow coloured cell, to be paired with the last light blue id2, since it is the final replacement and it is not found again in the dataframe. How would I go about computing such a comparison?

My dataframe (by accident the green values do not match)
[image]

I thought of using dictionaries and then replacing key value pairs, but what would the program do when it reaches the final id2 which is not present again in id1?

```
CHEMBL2443138 CHEMBL2443026 O00418
CHEMBL2443139 CHEMBL2443026 O00418
CHEMBL2443044 CHEMBL2443026 O00418
CHEMBL1092820 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1091317 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL2443026 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1089019 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1091829 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1091074 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1091450 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1091830 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1094038 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1091075 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1091459 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1089016 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1090045 CHEMBL1094018 O00418
CHEMBL1977874 CHEMBL1977874 O00418
CHEMBL3327225 CHEMBL1989805 O00418
CHEMBL2006263 CHEMBL437612  O00418
```

Comment: please paste the data and format as code in the question. Helps to copy and replicate

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan added that.

Comment: the green cells do not match. is that a typo?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan fixed in in the code part of the data. Apologies it was a much larger dataset and I was trying to provide a small working example.